# Horizontally and vertically align rotated text

Tags: html, css

I've scratched my head for hours with that tiny problem, I want to center horizontally a rotated text in a div and also have it vertically align to the bottom, and the all need to be responsive.
I managed to achieve that by setting some fixed value, but as expected it break when I resize the screen.

Here's my CSS and HTML:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left-side {
  position: relative;
  width: 6.04%;
  height: 76.339vh;
  margin-top: 10.714vh;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 87.92%;
  height: calc(100% - 10.714vh);
  margin-top: 10.714vh;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 76.339vh;
}

.right-side {
  width: calc(6.04% - 2px);
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.rotated {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-150%);
  top: calc(76.339vh - 10.714vh);
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/grids-responsive-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="pure-g">
  <div class="left-side">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="hero">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/830/1680/855.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="rotated">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The header is split in three parts, the third one is the one containing that rotated text, that is supposed to always be centered horizontally and vertically align with the bottom of the picture.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: but I suggest you look into - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and the clue.

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: It's how Stack add it to the snippet actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) clue, I managed to solve my problem by using `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` and only rotating the text by -180°.

A snippet of the final code:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left-side {
  position: relative;
  width: 6.04%;
  height: 76.339vh;
  margin-top: 10.714vh;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 87.92%;
  height: calc(100% - 10.714vh);
  margin-top: 10.714vh;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 76.339vh;
}

.right-side {
  width: 6.04%;
  position: relative;
  height: 76.339vh;
  margin-top: 10.714vh;
}

.rotated {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

p {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/grids-responsive-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="pure-g">
  <div class="left-side">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="hero">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/830/1680/855.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="rotated">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
}

.left-side {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 5%;
   height: 76.339vh;
   margin-top: 10.714vh;
}

.content {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 87.92%;
   height: calc(100% - 10.714vh);
   margin-top: 10.714vh;
}

.hero {
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   img {
       object-fit: cover;
       width: 100%;
       height: 76.339vh;
   }
}

.right-side {
     margin-right: 5%;
}

.rotated {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       p {
       writing-mode: vertical-lr;
       white-space: nowrap;
       font-size: 1em;
       line-height: 2em;
       letter-spacing: 1px;
       width: 100%;
   }
}
```

At the end of the day i wouldn't recommend using 'absolute' to position elements while needing a responsive page.

Use FlexBox instead it's easy use this [link](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) to easily learn about it.

Comment: The use of `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` is what I needed, but the rest of your code doesn't fit what I need.
I posted a snippet on the comments with an answer that solve it.